# crino/instagram-ios-sdk -Redirect URI does not match registered redirect URI

Tags: ios, sdk, uri, instagram

I am using `instagram-ios-sdk` and have configured the redirect URI as well as client id in my native application, but when i run my app and login using `instagram credentials` it gives me the following error,

```
{"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthException", "error_message": "Redirect URI does not match registered             redirect URI"}
```

I have set the redirect URI to **ig[clientId]://**

Have I missed anything here?

Answer (score 5):

Your Redirect URI should be : "ig" + "YOUR CLIENTID" + "://authorize"

Ex:  igyp5440d263fb4736m3740af876dd78pa://authorize

Comment: What should be the redirect URL for Android? This one fails.